# Heroku Autocomplete causing “Can't locate local/lib.pm” Error

Tags: ruby, macos, perl, heroku, terminal

I tried `brew update` and after the **Heroku autocomplete** installation I started getting the following error. How can I solve this issue?

> Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
> local::lib module) (@INC contains: /Users/franklin/perl5/lib/perl5
> /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
> /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0
> /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
> /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/5.28.0
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0).
>
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

[image: “Can't locate local/lib.pm” Error]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's trying to use the [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) Perl module. That creates a Perl library directory in your local directory so you don't have to install modules as root.

I don't know why that tool didn't do that for you (and you should tell those maintainers about that). You can install it yourself though:

- [Download the latest local::lib](https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/H/HA/HAARG/local-lib-2.000024.tar.gz)
- Untar the file and change into that directory
- run `perl Makefile.PL --bootstrap && make install`

I wish this was a bit easier so you could just use a quick `cpan` command to do it. There's also quite a bit [about local::lib on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=local%3A%3Alib+%5Bperl%5D).

Other advice has been to remove an offending line from *.bash_profile*, but something else in the tool might expect whatever that sets up.

Comment: Both `cpan` and `cpanm` (at least up to date versions of them) will install to the local::lib by default if executed without write access to the Perl's sitelib, this can be used to install local::lib itself. Additionally `cpanm -l ~/perl5 local::lib` will do this regardless of permissions, and a standalone `cpanm` script can be downloaded from https://cpanmin.us.

Comment: I don't think I added that feature to `cpan`, but maybe it's there. It can certainly use it once it's installed.